# restart fragment class when back button press

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have a fragment that is part of tab view. I want to restart this fragment when I press back button. but i don't know how to refresh it.
i tried some codes like this:
[Restart fragment inside activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989300/restart-fragment-inside-activity) but it didn't work.

here is a code for detecting back button:

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                // handle back button




                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

here is a fragment class button:

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

  static ListView list;


static String[] numbers_text = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven",
        "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen" };
String[] songs = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
        "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };



MainCustomList adapter;




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    adapter = new MainCustomList(this.getActivity(), numbers_text);
         list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);


         return view;
}
```

main:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

 }
```

Comment: How many fragments do you have in your TabLayout and what is the position of the fragment that you are trying to refresh ?

Comment: I have three tabs and it is third one.

Comment: check my solution below and see if it worked for you. (Are you using the Support library ?)

Comment: For **Android SDK >= 21** you may see my answer:
[How to restart fragment from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69621972/11898169)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this code:

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass) 
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_container_id)

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .detach(fragment)
                    .attach(fragment)
                    .commit();
```

& this will cause your `fragment`'s `OnCreateView` method **to be called** again & refresh its layout.

**UPDATE:**

When using the `Support Library`, you could access your fragment this way:

```
int YOUR_FRAGMENT_POSITION = 2; // in your case you wanna access the 3rd fragment, 0 indexed

YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(YOUR_FRAGMENT_POSITION);
```

And use the same code snippet above:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .detach(fragment)
                        .attach(fragment)
                        .commit();
```

If you try to access your `fragment` via the `PagerAdapter`, you may end up with an `IllegalStateException`, telling you that the fragment has failed to save its `state`.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me show you something that I figured out the last time I got across the same issue.

Comment: Oh I see... anyway glad I could help :)

Comment: @MohammedAoufZouag I also had the same issue, however, I can't figure out how to do this? Where should I put this codes?

Comment: @Woppi use this code within the code of the fragments' host activity.

Comment: hey @MohammedAoufZouag, getFragmentManager is depricated! is there any other way?

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager` is what you're looking for now.