# How to open a view in a fragment with an onClick method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, setcontentview

I have a floating action button in my layout, and I would like it to open another view when clicked. I read from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571018/5279711) answer that a good way to handle click events was this:

```
public class AllTasksFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_tasks, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View rootView) {
    switch (rootView.getId()) {
        case R.id.fab:

            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_new_task);

            break;
    }
}}
```

But, because `setContentView` method can't be used in fragments, Android Studio returns an error: `Cannot resolve method setContentView(int)`.

**What can I use instead of setContentView  to bring up another view through onClick method? Or do I have to approach this in a completely different way?**

Comment: I don't think that it's possible in fragments. But what you can do is "refreshing" the fragment's layout.

Comment: @DeveloperX I see! Can you point me towards an example/a tutorial on how this refreshing is done?

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461560/restart-fragment-class-when-back-button-press/33461612#33461612

Comment: @DeveloperX Thanks for the link, though the answer's solution didn't work in my case. I ended up handling the click event in my main activity. I was incorrectly trying to open a fragment though I realized I only needed to open a new activity.

Comment: Pleasure. Good luck !