# How restart Fragment in my Activity - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an activity that have 3 fragment inside. I need restart a first fragment in my activity with click on Button.

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFrag(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
adapter.addFrag(new CategoryFragment(), "Category");
adapter.addFrag(new FilterFragment(), "Filter");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I test the following way but doesn't work and show error:
[refresh fragment at reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: this way doesn't work an show error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reload your fragment with this:

```
FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tr.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, instanceFragment);
tr.commit()
```

Being `instanceFragment` the instance of the fragment you wanna to reload and `fragment_layout` the `FrameLayout` component in your activity layout XML file.

Comment: what is "your_fragment_container" and "yourFragmentInstance"?

Comment: `yourFragmentInstance` is the new instance of the fragment you wanna to reload, in your case, the first one; `your_fragment_container` is the `FrameLayout` in your XML layout file. I have updated my answer

Comment: for anyone looking for a method to reload a fragment without facing an `IllegalStateException` use the code described above in the fragments' host activity

Answer (score 5):

For **Android SDK >= 21** you may use this approach:
In your Activity class add function `restartFragment`

```
fun restartFragment(fragmentId: Int) {
    val currentFragment = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentId)!!

    this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .detach(currentFragment)
        .commit()
    this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .attach(currentFragment)
        .commit()
}
```

In your Fragment call

```
(requireActivity() as <YourActivityClassName>).restartFragment(id, R.id.<your_fragment_id>)
```

Personally I took R.id.<your_fragment_id> from my nav_graph as `R.id.settings_fragment` and  as `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

On button click you check if the current position of your ViewPager is bigger than 0 (first position)  and set it to the first position, like this:

```
if(viewPager.getCurrentItem>0){
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```