# Restart Fragment With New Argument

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have FragmentProductDetail, in the `onCreateView()` i write :

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
    idToRead = getArguments().getInt("productId");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
} else {
    idToRead = -1;
}
```

Then how to restart this fragment and put new argument? i've try write this :

```
Bundle arg = new Bundle();
arg.putInt("productId", idToRead);
Fragment fragCurrent = context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(fragCurrent);
fragTransaction.attach(fragCurrent);
fragCurrent.setArguments(arg);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

but both of them give me error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active`

Comment: you know that with `fragTransaction.detach(fragCurrent);` without `fragTransaction.commit();` actually nothing happend? ... moreover: the commit does not happen immediately

Comment: Sorry i don't know, i am just follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989300/restart-fragment-inside-activity

Comment: i've tried put fragTransaction.commit() after detach() but still gives me same error

Comment: why are you detaching just to reattach again?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are attaching your fragment for the first time ?

Comment: @Kuffs, i try to reload the fragment and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989300/restart-fragment-inside-activity)

Comment: @AbhishekJain abhsek, i put this inside MainActivity.java `getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentProductList())
                .commit();`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but sorry i already have my own solution which is suitable for my app

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fragmentManager.replace()` function to replace fragments. Try this:

```
Bundle arg = new Bundle();
arg.putInt("productId", idToRead);
Fragment fragCurrent = context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
fragCurrent.setArguments(arg);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragCurrent, fragCurrent.getTag());
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentaion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) :

> setArguments
>
> Added in API level 11 void setArguments (Bundle args) Supply the
>   construction arguments for this fragment. **This can only be called**
>   **before the fragment has been attached to its activity**; that is, you
>   should call it immediately after constructing the fragment. The
>   arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and
>   creation.

You can't call `Fragment.setArguments()` once the fragment is attached to its activity.

Do something like this instead:

```
Bundle arg = new Bundle();
arg.putInt("productId", idToRead);
Fragment fragCurrent = context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(fragCurrent);
FragmentProductList fragment = new FragmentProductList();
fragment.setArguments(arg);
fragTransaction.attach(fragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Note that : Here you are creating a new instance of your fragment and then attaching it. You can't change the arguments of the same instance of fragment once you've set them.

Or if you want to put new values to the same fragment then you can use [`getArguments()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()). Something like this :

```
Fragment fragCurrent = context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
Bundle arg = fragCurrent.getArguments();
arg.putInt("productId", idToRead);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(fragCurrent);
fragTransaction.attach(fragCurrent);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my own solution which is fit for me.

In MainActivity.java i create map for all of the fragment which want to save some global variable

```
public static Map<Object, Object> dataSaver = new HashMap<>();
```

Then when i want to reload my fragment with new data, i write like this

```
Fragment fragCurrent = context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(fragCurrent);
MainActivity.dataSaver.put("productId", idToRead);
fragTransaction.attach(fragCurrent);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Then inside `onCreateView()` i put this

```
if (MainActivity.dataSaver.get("productId") != null) {
    idToRead = getArguments().getInt("productId");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    MainActivity.dataSaver.remove("productId");
} else {
    idToRead = -1;
}
```